# How can I scrape text from the table in this page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape words and their meaning from the word list on [this](https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html) this page using `bs4` and `selenium`, although I'm not sure how I can loop through the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags after I get the table html from the `bs4` `find_all` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = "https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html"

driver.get(root)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'class': 'tablex border1'})[0]
```

Now in the table variable I have the html for the whole table, here's a snippet from the start and end:

```
<table class="tablex border1"> <tbody><tr><td><a href="https://gre.graduateshotline.com/a.pl?word=introspection" target="_blank">introspection</a></td>
<td>examining one's own thoughts and feelings</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="https://gre.graduateshotline.com/a.pl?word=philanthropist" target="_blank">philanthropist</a></td>
.
.
.
<tr><td><a href="https://gre.graduateshotline.com/a.pl?word=refine" target="_blank">refine</a></td>
<td>make or become pure cultural </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I'm not sure how I can access the words and their meanings using it. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to iterate through all the tablerows, and pull out the text from a pair of `td` elements. Is your question how to get the text from an element with beautifulsoup4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate through all the tablerows, and pull out the text from a pair of td elements.

```
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
  tds = row.find_all("td")
  print(f"{tds[0].text}: {tds[1].text}")

...
repel: refuse to accept/cause dislike
superimpose: put something on the top
centurion: leader of a unit of 100 soldiers
```

For what its worth, you can use `python-requests` to get a webpage's content without spinning up a browser:

```
import requests

content = requests.get(root).text
```

Comment: A follow up question, in the link, bs4 can't detect the tables below that are hidden. How would I scrape those?

Answer (score 2):

Now your table data is generating and you can collect your desired data  this way. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
link = 'https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html'
r = requests.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
table_data = pd.read_html(r.text)
print(table_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to access the *first* and *second* `td` under the `<table>` to get the correct tags.

You can use the [`nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS selector to specifically access the *first* or *second* `<td>`. For example: `td:nth-of-type(1)`

To use a CSS selector, use the [`select_one()`](http://td:nth-of-type(1)) method instead of `.find()`.

Note:

- There is no need to use `Selenium` this can be done with the [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, which will greatly improve the performance of your code.
- Since are only looking for one `<table>`, use the [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method which returns the *first* found tag, instead of `find_all()`.

Here is a complete working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


root = "https://www.graduateshotline.com/gre-word-list.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(root).content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "tablex border1"})

fmt_string = "{:<50} {:<30}"
for tag in table:
    try:
        print(
            fmt_string.format(
                tag.select_one("td:nth-of-type(1)").text,
                tag.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text,
            )
        )
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Output:

```
introspection                                      examining one's own thoughts and feelings
philanthropist                                     one who loves mankind         
antidote                                           medicine used against a poison or a disease
strive                                             to make great efforts, to struggle
ambidextrous                                       able to use the left hand or the right equally well
precursors                                         a person or thing that precedes, as in a  process or job.
retrospective                                      Looking back on past          
introvert                                          one who turns towards himself
```

Using `{:<50} {:<30}` will align the characters with a length of 50 and 30 to the left, in order to prettify the output.

Comment: I didn't know you could format string like that thanks! But I'm planning on storing these in a db anyway